# Disable visualization of download progress

Tags: windows-10, firefox

I'm using Windows 10 and Firefox (the most recent versions).

When downloading files, the Firefox icon gets the visualization for the download progress (green background):

[image: The green background indicates the download progress in Firefox.]

Is there any way to disable this behaviour either in Firefox or in Windows? I get distracted by this quite a lot.